# How to use a web vulnerability scanner to autenthicate through in order to do the scan

Tags: penetration-test, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability-scanners, scan

I thinking about use a various mix of different scanner such as:

**Burp-suite

Acunetix Vulnerability Scanner

Arachni

Owasp Zed Attack Proxy Project

Vega

W3af**

though we have **Active directory** that is integrated with **Identify Manager**.
(All the operations are performed in Novel Identity Manager (or Mostly Are)
and are forwared to Active Directory).

Now is my question

How to use a web vulnerability scanner to autenthicate through ad in order to the scan?

what would you recommend to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Arachni does a pretty good job at logging in to the application. You can check http://support.arachni-scanner.com/kb/general-use/logging-in-and-maintaining-a-valid-session for additional information.

Comment: pretty much Arachni spawns a headless browser called PhantomJS(http://phantomjs.org/) and Watir(http://watir.com/) (Ruby representation of Selenium webdriver). With that being said, you can write your own Ruby (.rb) or JavaScript (.js) script to authenticate through the login screen of your web application.